# How do I override default Answers on a Mockito mock?

Tags: java, mockito

I have the following code:

```
private MyService myService;

@Before
public void setDependencies() {
    myService = Mockito.mock(MyService.class, new StandardServiceAnswer());
    Mockito.when(myService.mobileMethod(Mockito.any(MobileCommand.class), Mockito.any(Context.class)))
            .thenAnswer(new MobileServiceAnswer());
}
```

My intention is that all calls to the mocked `myService` should answer in a standard manner. However calls to `mobileMethod` (which is public) should be answered in a specific way.

What I'm finding is that, when I get to the line to add an answer to calls to `mobileMethod`, rather than attaching the `MobileServiceAnswer`, Java is actually invoking `myService.mobileMethod`, which results in an NPE.

Is this possible? It would seem like it should be possible to override a default answer.
If it is possible, what is the correct way to do it?

### Update

Here are my `Answer`s:

```
private class StandardServiceAnswer implements Answer<Result> {
    public Result answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) {
        Object[] args = invocation.getArguments();

        Command command = (Command) args[0];
        command.setState(State.TRY);

        Result result = new Result();
        result.setState(State.TRY);
        return result;
    }
}

private class MobileServiceAnswer implements Answer<MobileResult> {
    public MobileResult answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) {
        Object[] args = invocation.getArguments();

        MobileCommand command = (MobileCommand) args[0];
        command.setState(State.TRY);

        MobileResult result = new MobileResult();
        result.setState(State.TRY);
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: If you have this in your ```@Before``` method, then you shouldn't be able to use ```myService``` in the tests. Aren't you hiding an instance variable? Or is it just for demonstration? Also, how does StandardServiceAnswer look like?

Comment: I've updated my sample to clear this up. `myService` is a private field in the test class

Comment: Sorry for the confusion... it was for demonstration purposes.

Comment: Add a short test method that demonstrates the problem.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Two unrelated surprises are causing this problem together:

- `Mockito.any(Class)` [doesn't actually return an object of that class](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22822512/1426891). It returns `null` and stashes a "disregard the parameter and accept anything" matcher on a [secret internal matcher stack called ArgumentMatcherStorage](https://github.com/mockito/mockito/blob/master/src/org/mockito/internal/progress/ArgumentMatcherStorageImpl.java). That argument value will actually be null, but in most cases you won't see it.
- The statement `when(foo.bar()).thenReturn(baz)` actually calls `foo.bar()`, always. Typically this has no side effects—especially if you're stubbing its first chain of actions—so you don't notice it.

During the stub, Java calls your real answer, and tries to call `setState` on your matcher-based (null) argument. Based on Java evaluation order, this makes sense: Mockito calls your answer as if it were the system under test calling your answer, because there's no way for Mockito to know that the call to `mobileMethod` immediately precedes a call to `when`. It hasn't gotten there yet.

The answer is to use the "doVerb" methods, such as `doAnswer`, `doReturn`, and `doThrow`, which I like to call "Yoda syntax". Because these contain `when(object).method()` instead of `when(object.method())`, Mockito has a chance to deactivate your previously-set expectations, and your original answer is never triggered. It would look like this:

```
MyService myService = Mockito.mock(MyService.class, new StandardServiceAnswer());
Mockito.doAnswer(new MobileServiceAnswer())
    .when(myService).mobileMethod(
          Mockito.any(MobileCommand.class), Mockito.any(Context.class));
```

It's worth noting that *the exception is the only reason that your override didn't work*. Under normal circumstances "when-thenVerb" is absolutely fine for overriding, and will backtrack over the previous action so as not to throw off consecutive actions like `.thenReturn(...).thenThrow(...)`. It's also worth noting that `when(mobileMethod(command, context))` would have changed `command` and `context` during the stub without throwing an exception, which can introduce subtle testing gaps.

Some developers go so far as to prefer the "doVerb-when" syntax over the "when-thenVerb" syntax at all times, because it has that nice behavior of never calling the other mock. You're welcome to come to the same conclusion—"doVerb" does everything "when-thenVerb" does, but is safer to use when overriding behavior in mocks and spies. I prefer "when" syntax myself—it's a little nicer to read, and it does type-check return values—as long as you remember that sometimes "doVerb" is the only way to get where you need to go.

Comment: Thank you for this! I'd spent several hours debugging a related issue, and when the lightbulb finally went off of "oh, I wonder if it's because...", your post was the first thing I found that confirmed my suspicions, allowed me to write a small test to confirm it, and provided a simple solution. Thanks again!

Comment: Thanks for the "Yoda syntax" phrase ;)

Answer (score -2):

What you want to do is valid, and when I do it it works:

```
private Properties props;

@Before 
public void setUp() {
    props = mock(Properties.class, new Answer<String>() {
        @Override
     public String answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) throws Throwable {
         return "foo";
     }
    } );
    when(props.get("override")).thenAnswer(new Answer<String>() {
        @Override
     public String answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) throws Throwable {
         return "bar";
     }
    } );
}

@Test
public void test() {
    assertEquals("foo", props.get("no override"));
    assertEquals("bar", props.get("override"));
}
```

So step through the execution of your testcase with a debugger to find out what you're doing that's different from this simple case.